# prestashop choose language in header of BO

Tags: prestashop

I would like to make a header section for a fast language change. Currently I have to go to my profile to change the language.

```
<div id="header_changeLang" style="">
    <a class="change_lang" {if $lang_iso=="lt"}style="text-decoration:underline;"{/if} href="{$thisIndex}&change_lang=4">LT</a>
    <a class="change_lang" {if $lang_iso=="lv"}style="text-decoration:underline;"{/if} href="{$thisIndex}&change_lang=5">LV</a>
    <a class="change_lang" {if $lang_iso=="en"}style="text-decoration:underline;"{/if} href="{$thisIndex}&change_lang=1">EN</a>
    <a class="change_lang" {if $lang_iso=="ru"}style="text-decoration:underline;"{/if} href="{$thisIndex}&change_lang=6">RU</a>
</div>


{literal}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".change_lang").each(function() {
            link = $(this);
            langName = link.html();
            langId = link.attr("href")[link.attr("href").length-1];
            link.attr("href", "index.php{/literal}{foreach $smarty.get as $param=>$val}{if $param == "controller"}?{else}&{/if}{$param}={$val}{/foreach}{literal}&change_lang="+langId);
            //console.log(langName +" - "+ link.attr("href"));
        });
    });
</script>
{/literal}
```

I tried this, but I got a wrong URL. I tried to transplant the language block into `DashboardzoneTwo`, but something seems to be wrong. I cannot see anything.

Any way to correct the change lang block?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$currentIndex` instead of `$thisIndex`

As for `&change_lang=4`, are you implementing some code that would handle that parameter?

For more information, open the file `[ADMIN DIR]/themes/default/template/header.tpl` and add `{debug}` somewhere, this will open a popup with all smarty variables.

Comment: Yap, i attached some code. Check this. $currentIndex didnt help me.

Comment: Where's `$thisIndex` coming from? I couldn't find this variable on my shop!

Comment: replace `{if $param == "controller"}` by `{if $val@iteration == 1}` and maybe you'll get a better result

Comment: I change it to $currentIndex. UnLoCo didnt help this. Any other ways to change fast LANG in BO header?